# Using for loop to compare two strings character by character in bash

Tags: bash, sh

I am writing a bash script that loops over a large file of data which i have extracted the key parts I need to use. It seems quite trivial when I was trying to do it but all I need to do is something akin to,

```
string1=...
string2=...    
correct=0
for i in 1..29
do
   if [string1[i] == string2[i]]
   then
      correct=correct+1
   fi
done
```

When I tried doing something like this I get a `Bad Substitution` which I assume is because some of the key's look like this,

```
  `41213343323455122411141331555 - key` 
  `3113314233111 22321112433111* - answer`
```

The spaces and occational `*` that are found don't need special treatment in my case, just a simple comparison of each index.

```
#!/bin/bash
answersCorrect=0
for i in $(nawk 'BEGIN{ for(i=1;i<=29;i++) print i}')
do
  if [ "${answer:i:1}" = "${key:i:1}" ]
   then
    answersCorrect=$answersCorrect+1 #this line#
  fi
done
```

I am getting no compiler errors now however I don't think i'm incrementing `answersCorrect` correctly. When I output it it is something like `0+1+1+1` instead of just `3` (this segment is being used inside a while loop)

Fixed Solution for that line : `answersCorrect=$((answersCorrect+1))`

Comment: Start here: https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: what a handy website. I get a lot of text in yellow mentioning, "In POSIX sh, string indexing is undefined." can you not reference string index's like this in sh?

Comment: You might be using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang line. If you use `#!/bin/bash` (or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`) instead, you can use string indexing like that. It might not be what you think it is, by the way: it's the substring *starting* at index *i*. To get a single character, you need `${key:i:1}`.

Comment: Ah that might be the case then, cause I am indeed using `#!/bin/sh`. After fixing the `${key:i:1}` I still get a `Bad Substitution` I don't believe I'm able to switch which shell I'm using though. Not sure why this error is appearing though? I'm not substituting anything in this program.

Comment: After switching from `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash` I seem to now just get a `30: [: =: unary operator expected` but it still runs but it will print that 11 times lol

Comment: Can you update with your improved script with all the quoting and such in place?

Comment: @BenjaminW.if you would like to form an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The original problem is fixed by comments and some extra work of @Mikel.
An alternative is comparing the strings after converting the strings to lines.

```
diff --suppress-common-lines <(fold -w1 <<< "${string1}") <(fold -w1 <<< "${string2}") |
    grep -c "^<"
```